# How to start the admin dashboard template in modern mode?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

The admin dashboard shipped with extjs starts using the classic toolkit by default, and requires the user to click a button to switch to modern. (which inserts `?modern` in the url) Is there any way to make the dashboard start up in modern by default, replacing the modern tag with classic?

I've been looking through app.js, app.json and various other files but I can't seem to find anything related to what page to use as primary index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In index.html, on line 33, you will find the following:

```
profile = tags.desktop ? 'classic' : 'modern';
```

By switching the two so it looks like this:

```
profile = tags.desktop ? 'modern' : 'classic';
```

It will make modern the default profile. The toolkit switch still works but will now switch to classic instead of modern, adding `?classic` to the url.